# React.js - Pass data to parent method as a parameter from child

Tags: reactjs

I am simply trying to pass a value back up to a parent component when I invoke a method in a child component.

I have a parent component called `Job`. It renders a child component called `SummaryChart`. When a bar on the barchart is clicked from within `SummaryChart`, I want it to tell `Job` which bar was clicked, and to open a modal.

## Parent Component

```
class Job extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ...
    }

    this.getSequenceView = this.getSequenceView.bind(this);

  }

  getSequenceView(config, event)
  {
    console.log(config.someData);
    $('#help-modal').modal();
  }

render()
  {
    return (
      
      <SummaryChart
        handleBarClick={() => this.getSequenceView(config, event)}
      />

    );
  }
```

## Child Component

```
class SummaryChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: {
        chart: {
          events: {
            dataPointSelection:  function(event, chartContext, config) {
              props.handleBarClick(config, event);
            },
        }
     }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

I receive the following error when I click:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined

I'm thinking my error must lie in my parent component when I pass the prop to `SummaryChart`, but I don't know how else to tell the method to expect two arguments. Other examples have things like hard-coded props as arguments, but I want to use information from [ApexCharts click events](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/#dataPointSelection) to pass back up to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the method argument in the child call.

```
<SummaryChart
        handleBarClick={(config, event) => this.getSequenceView(config, event)}
      />
```